# Securing passphrase when using EncryptByPassword in SQL Server

Tags: sql-server, encryption

I'm securing a few columns of data throughout various tables on a shared hosting platform - due to permissions I'm having to use EncryptByPassword.

Are there any ideas on how I can secure the passphrase being used.  As far as I can see at some point it will be know, either by hardcoding in the database layer or adding as a parameter and supplying from my DAL calls.  Both these methods are not ideal as anyone could just look int the procedures or profile any calls to the database.

I'm on a shared hosting plan with godaddy, so don't have any direct access to the servers. I can't create masterkeys/certificates etc.

Possibly I could encrypt/decrypt in a common object that I could reference in my c# DAL?  Thoughts please?

Comment: `ENCRYPTBYPASSPHRASE` won't really do much for you if you can't trust the database with the key. You may as well do the encrypting/decrypting on the client side, and never transmit anything but encrypted (binary) values. This is basically the approach behind SQL Server's own Always Encrypted feature, except that that is transparent to client applications. (You might check if your hosting plan actually offers it -- from SQL Server 2016 SP1 onwards, it's available in all editions, not just Enterprise.)

Comment: Thanks for your reply - unfortunately not, think I will just have to implement something in .NET as you suggested for the time being.  Not really ideal for using the data outside of my ASP app but I guess I have no other choice at the moment.